# Exam class \ifincomplete not playing nicely with \include

Tags: include, exam

I often write exams of the form:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno,nocancelspace]{exam}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}\begin{framed}
  {\bfseries \large EXAMINATION}
\end{framed}\end{center}
\pagebreak
\cfoot{\ifincomplete{\textit{Question continues on next page.}}{}}

\begin{questions}
\include{question_catalogue/first_topic_qn}
\pagebreak
\include{question_catalogue/second_topic_qn}
\end{questions}
\cfoot{}\newpage
\ \vfill
\cfoot{\textit{This page is intentionally left blank.}}\newpage
\ \vfill 
\newpage
\ \vfill 
\newpage\ 
\ \vfill
\end{document}
```

And then each of the questions are in separate files, and are of the form:

```
\titledquestion{First topic}
This is a question on the first topic.
\begin{parts}
\part Answer this
\begin{solutionorbox}[\stretch{1}]
\end{solutionorbox}
\part Answer that
\begin{solutionorbox}[\stretch{1}]
\end{solutionorbox}
\pagebreak
\part Answer something else
\begin{solutionorbox}[\stretch{1}]
\end{solutionorbox}
\end{parts}
```

I have just noticed that the footer on the last page of the final question incorrectly says "Question continues on next page." Having played around with things it appears that the problem is the use of `\include`. When I switch the `\include` of the last question to `\input` the footer looks correct. While I'm happy I can write exams this way, it's a little unsatisfactory/hacky that I can't use a standard LaTeX command like `\include`. Are there any other ways around this problem?

Comment: `\include` should only be used at the top level not inside an environment, you want `\input` here. then use `\clearpage` before and after each `\input`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sounds like that's my problem (though presumably the document environment is an exception...)

Comment: the document environment isn't really an environment at all (it's a syntactic trick) that is things inside every environment except document are in a tex group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\include` is designed for top level constructs such as `\chapters` (specifically things where you need to save the document state so that units can be skipped with `\includeonly`). So you should use `\input` here. Changing the page header mid-document is most reliable at a forced page break `\include` uses  `\clearpage` before and after the `\included` text so perhaps that is what you want here.

```
\clearpage\input{zzzzz}\clearpage
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the command `\nomorequestions` immediately following the last question, all should be well.

Comment: Thanks. This does appear to work if I put `\nomorequestions` at the end of the file of the final question, but not if I put it in the top-level document. That's an improvement, but limits my ability to re-order the questions.